# Web2py error: <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> (ImportError('No module named version',), <traceback object at 0x0534C468>)

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, web2py

When running the commands in idle I can get an API call to work using oauth2. Then when trying to use the same lines of code in web2py I was getting an error that the web2py module wasn't found. So I installed Oauth2 into the module folder of the web2py project files.

This changed the error from the oauth2 module not found to 
 (ImportError('No module named version',), )

Any ideas to find a fix would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As an update I figured out that the issue was because Web2py doesn't support python 3 at this point in time.

Comment: web2py _does_ support Python 3, so the problem must lie elsewhere.